# AsyncTask onProgressUpdate(Double... value)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, double

I am using the `AsyncTask` to compute a double and then I want to publish this double value

```
private class CalcTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... parms){
        //Completes calculations and places them in a double

        double calc = 54.245555 //arbitrary number for this example
        publishProgress(calc);

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... calc){
        textview.setText("Value: " + calc);
    }
}
```

Currently the output is:

> Value: [L]java.lang.Double;@4054d180

Is there a way to just post the double value and not the hex address?

Comment: This has a similar root cause as the problem in your other question, too ([see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16662775/119114)).  The critical point is that **even if you pass a single value** to `publishProgress()`, `onProgressUpdate()` will be called back, and passed an **array** of values.  It's done that way to allow you the flexibility to pass 1..N progress values at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) representation of the `Double` array `calc` in `onProgressUpdate`. Just use the first element of the array:

```
textview.setText("Value: " + calc[0]);
```